# How to add a label inside the dropdown item with list inside the list (FLUTTER)

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> category = [
    {
      "name": "One",
      "detail": ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "detail": ['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "detail": ['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
    },
  ];
```

I want to add the name as the label in dropdown item, and the detail as the item. For example, as showing in the picture
[image]
The bold text should be the "name", the normal text will be the detail items

Comment: How do you create this dropdown menu, where is your code for that?

Comment: The image doesn't look like a dropdown..

Comment: the picture dropdown menu is using html to do, that just a sample, since i want to do it by using flutter

Comment: i want do like this
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2021/09/multi-select.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can give you an idea of how to possibly do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> category = [
    {
      "name": "One",
      "detail": ['11', '12', '13', '14']
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "detail": ['21', '22', '23', '24']
    },
    {
      "name": "three",
      "detail": ['31', '32', '33', '34']
    },
  ];

  late final List data;
  String? selectedItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    data = [
      for (final item in category)
        for (final value in item.values)
          if (value is List)
            for (final listValue in value) {'value': listValue, 'bold': false}
          else
            {'value': value, 'bold': true}
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: selectedItem,
                    items: [
                      for (final item in data)
                        item['bold'] == true
                            ? DropdownMenuItem(
                                enabled: false,
                                child: Text(item['value'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                            : DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: item['value'],
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                  child: Text(item['value']),
                                ))
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedItem = value;
                      });
                    }))));
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

In the `initState` I transform the data in a way so you have a list where each item corresponds to a dropdown item. With additional info whether it should be bold or not

Comment: Sorry, may I know if the list format is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355185/showing-the-dropdown-list-with-special-list-and-multiple-dynamic-dependent-dropd

how can generate it, I have been trying few days still cannot, Sorry I'm newbie in Flutter