# Showing the dropdown list with special List and Multiple Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List

Tags: flutter, list, drop-down-menu, dropdown

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> category123 = [
    {
      "name": "Python",
      "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
     
    },
    {
      "name": "Javascript",
      "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['21', '22', '23', '24'],
      
    },
    {
      "name": "PHP",
       "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['31', '32', '33', '34'],
     
    },
    {
      "name": "C#",
          "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['41', '42', '43', '44'],
  
    },
    {
      "name": "Java",
           "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['51', '52', '53', '54'],
 
    },
    {
      "name": "C++",
          "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['61', '62', '63', '64'],
  
    },
     {
      "name": "Erlang",
          "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['71', '72', '73', '74'],
  
    },
  ];
```

Is it possibly make this List become like picture result? and I also want the detail (list) will be display in other list based on the which "name" is selected.

[image]

For the dependents, if i select the JavaScript in selection, in another dropdown list should show the detail List of the Javascript including 11, 12, 13, 14

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> category123 = [
    {
      "name": "Python",
      "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
    },
    {
      "name": "Javascript",
      "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['21', '22', '23', '24'],
    },
    {
      "name": "PHP",
      "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['31', '32', '33', '34'],
    },
    {
      "name": "C#",
      "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['41', '42', '43', '44'],
    },
    {
      "name": "Java",
      "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['51', '52', '53', '54'],
    },
    {
      "name": "C++",
      "department": "second-choice",
      "detail": ['61', '62', '63', '64'],
    },
    {
      "name": "Erlang",
      "department": "first-choice",
      "detail": ['71', '72', '73', '74'],
    },
  ];

  late final List data;
  dynamic selectedItem;
  String? selectedDetail;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final groups = groupBy(category123, (Map e) => e['department']);

    data = [
      for (final item in groups.entries)
        for (final value in [item.key, ...item.value])
          if (value is Map)
            {'value': value, 'bold': false}
          else
            {'value': value, 'bold': true}
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
      children: [
        DropdownButton<dynamic>(
            value: selectedItem,
            items: [
              for (final item in data)
                item['bold'] == true
                    ? DropdownMenuItem(
                        enabled: false,
                        child: Text(item['value'],
                            style:
                                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                    : DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item['value'],
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                          child: Text(item['value']['name']),
                        ))
            ],
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = value;
              });
            }),
        if (selectedItem != null)
          DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedItem['detail'].contains(selectedDetail)
                  ? selectedDetail
                  : null,
              items: [
                for (final item in selectedItem['detail'])
                  DropdownMenuItem(value: item, child: Text(item))
              ],
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedDetail = value;
                });
              })
      ],
    ))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I stuck this problem few days already, u save me, Thank you again